# How to fix "The Google Maps Android API Street View service has been disabled for this application."

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I Wanted To Run The Street-view For a Certain Location And when i switched to it on the app. 
It Gave me this error.

```
The Google Maps Android API Street View service has been disabled for this application.
```

I have Maps API For Native Android Enabled in Developers Console 
And Also Street View Static API enabled . Could Somebody please explain the cause of the error?

Comment: Can you provide the complete error message? For this issue, it might be because of an incorrectly configured project, or an invalid API key. Please check that the API key is properly included in your app and make sure that your project is also linked to a valid billing account.

Comment: @Pagemag The API Key was Valid, I did a bit of research and found out that you need to pay for street view service. So eventually I had to discard the project.